# why i get error when i define new intent?

Tags: java, android

```
package islam.work;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer begin;
    Intent inti;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        begin = MediaPlayer.create(Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity.this, R.drawable.media);
        begin.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {



                    inti = new Intent(this,  program.class); //error here



                    startActivity(inti);

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) put some line breaks in your code (2) what is the error?

Comment: Is `program` an activity class? If so, it must be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: You are using `this` as the first parameter of the `Intent` constructor (which requires a `Context`) but `this` refers to the instance of an enclosing object which, in your code, is a `Thread` and not a `Context`. Change `this` to `Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity.this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
inti = new Intent(this,  program.class);
```

to

```
inti = new Intent(Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity .this,  program.class);
```

Since you are constructing your `Intent` inside of a `Thread`, `this` is referring to the `Thread` instead of your `Activity Context`.